# How can I check if an identifier is dunder or class-private (i.e. will be mangled)?

Tags: python, identifier, magic-methods, name-mangling

I'm writing a project that gives advice about variable names, and I want it to tell if a name matches any of the [reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). The first one ("private") is pretty straightforward, just `name.startswith('_')`, but dunder and class-private names are more complicated. Is there any built-in function that can tell me? If not, what are the internal rules Python uses?

For dunder, checking `name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')` doesn't work because that would match `'__'` for example. Maybe a regex like `^__\w+__$` would work?

For class-private, `name.startswith('__')` doesn't work because dunder names aren't mangled, nor are names with just underscores like `'___'`. So it seems like I'd have to check if the name starts with two underscores, doesn't end with two underscores, and contains at least one non-underscore character. Is that right? In code:

```
name.startswith('__') and not name.endswith('__') and any(c != '_' for c in name)
```

I'm mostly concerned about the edge cases, so I want to make sure I get the rules 100% correct. I read [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/4518341) but there's not enough detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Dunder

Based on [`is_dunder_name` in `Objects/typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/148f32913573c29250dfb3f0d079eb8847633621/Objects/typeobject.c#L3299-L3306) (using `str.isascii` from Python 3.7):

```
len(name) > 4 and name.isascii() and name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')
```

Alternatively, that regex `^__\w+__$` would work, but it would need [`re.ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) enabled to make sure `\w` only matches ASCII characters.

#### Class-private

The rules are documented under [Identifiers (Names)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

```
name.startswith('__') and not name.endswith('__')
```

(Sidenote: `not name.endswith('__')` ensures that the name contains at least one non-underscore.)

There's also a C implementation at [`_Py_Mangle` in `Python/compile.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd46174a5a09a54e5ae1077909f923f56a7cf710/Python/compile.c#L236-L258), but it includes a check for a dot, when, strictly speaking, a name with a dot is an "attribute reference", not a name. That'd be equivalent to:

```
name.startswith('__') and not name.endswith('__') and not '.' in name
```

---

P.S. I can barely read C, so take these translations with a grain of salt.